# findOne() to return boolean value - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am running into a problem in express js using mongoose.
I have a manager layer that communicates with model layer (using mongoose).
In the manager layer i have the CRUD functions that can be used by controllers.
In the manager layer i have a function "checkCredentials()" which will search the given username and password in MongoDB and return true or false to the controller.
The problem is that function "checkCredentials()" is returning undefined.
Following is the code , i will be really thankful if anyone can help.

```
function checkCredentials(uName,Pass){      

    librarian.findOne({ UserName: uName , Password: Pass}, function (err, doc){     
        console.log('uName: '+uName);
        console.log('Pass: '+Pass); // this will print on console , working fine

        if (doc === null) {            
            return false; // this will return undefined to the controller

        } else {            
            return true;  // this will return undefined to the controller          
        }
}
```

Comment: See if there's any error by adding `if(err) console.log(err)` before `if(doc === null)..`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that this way. findOne working asynchronous while the function need to return the value immediately.
so the "return" you wrote in the findOne it's not the one for the function checkCredentials

Edit:
If you want to do it right - you need to pass a callback function to the checkCredentials - then when the findOne completed, execute the callback with the parameters you need

Comment: I go for promises, when dealing with Mongoose - just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkCredentials(uName,Pass, callback){      

    librarian.findOne({ UserName: uName , Password: Pass}, function (err, doc){     
        console.log('uName: '+uName);
        console.log('Pass: '+Pass); // this will print on console , working fine
        if(err)
               return callback(err, false);
        if (doc === null) {            
            return callback(null, false); // this will return undefined to the controller

        } else {            
            return callback(null, true);  // this will return undefined to the controller          
        }
}
```

You can try this code.

Comment: Tried it. Facing this issue:
managers\manager.js:40
            return callback(null, true);  // this will return undefined to the
                   ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at managers\manager.js:40:20
    at node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:117
4:16
    at node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Comment: i don't think "return callback it's a good one... because the return not related to the checkCredentials, but the findOne